# Python/selenium How to interact with a fileUpload window without using Find_element?

Tags: python, file-upload, selenium

I'm using selenium webdriver to automate some test for a page.

My page has three radio buttons. The third button when clicked pops up a file upload window.

So the user flow would be like this: Clicks on radiobutton, the window pops uo, the user select a file, then the file is uploaded and the radio button sets checked.

First I was doing this:
find_element(By.ID, 'file_uploader').sendKeys(filepath)

This worked well, except that the radio button never was clicked and so it wasn't checked after the upload.

Next I tried this:
find_element(By.ID, 'radio-button-id').click() #radio button is clicked and set checked

Now the fileUpload window raises and I want to write the path of the file in the file name field (the cursor is already there when the window appears)

I can't find the way to this last thing. I tried switch to the new window, sendKeys, actionChains.sendKeys, etc, nothing works.

I can not make a find_element of the file name field in the upload window.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some problems with file dialogs. No one of those approaches you suggested worked for me as well. Anyway, I realized that this kind of thing must be done outside of selenium. Reason: WebDriver does not manage dialogs, since they are domain of the operating system. The solution I've found so far is waiting for the user input.